# Query about for loop initialization, condition, and increment

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and programming word, and I'm learning bout For Loop. Now I have studied that In loop works if there are conditions and increment in the body of loop like:

```
for(int i=10;i<15;i++)
```

But i have seen a code on some website and it was like this:

```
for(;NULL;)
{
cout<<"hello";
}
```

Now, some one can please explain what's it's output and how it works?

Comment: This does an explicit conversion of `Null` (whatever that variable is) to `bool` and uses that as the condition. I.e. it's equivalent to a `while`.

Comment: Was it `Null` or `NULL`? If the former, you'll need to add what `Null` means (is it a variable? a macro? something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the condition your loop will be executed, now your condition is NULL and Null means there is no condition present so it will not take anything if it's condition itself is Null so it just skip from the loop and it will not print anything.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, all 3 expressions controlling the `for` loop are optional. This makes the language powerful. In your case you're missing the expression that initialises (typically) a loop counter, and the expression that's typically used to increment a loop counter. What you have is the *stopping condition*.

If `Null` is something that has an *contextual conversion* to a `bool` type then the program will compile. Otherwise it won't. Let's assume that it does:

If that converted `bool` value is `false` then the loop body never runs.

If that converted `bool` value is `true` then the loop body will run. (Note that it's possible that the conversion *might* change the converted object, so perhaps `false` is eventually yielded so the loop does eventually terminate!)

Comment: The beauty of user defined conversions is that they can also be nasty little things that mutate the converted object. So the forever part is only likely.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed, I've pinched that.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop construct can be generalized to the following.

```
for(initializationStatement; testExpression; updateStatement) {
    // codes 
}
```

In the code example that you've given `initializationStatement` & `updateStatement` have been omitted i.e. they do nothing.

`for` loop gets executed until the `testExpression` is `true`. In C/C++ any expression that gets evaluated to `0` is false and anything that gets evaluated some other value is true. `Null` in this case is this case is presumably convertible to `bool` and yields false. Since the `testExpression` is `false` the loop never gets executed.

Comment: We don't know what `Null` is. My answer is an attempt to cover all bases.

Comment: Correct. Thanks @Bathsheba. I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for which the loop should run itself is `Null`. Thus the for-loop will not execute. You should have at least one valid condition so that for-loop gets executed once and print hello